# Disable jQuery on mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I want to disable a fade in script on mobile devices, the code below is what I have tried. However it seems to disable all the elements from view on all resolutions, I am using `display: none` on each element in my CSS which I think when the jQuery disables the script the CSS comes into play and i'm not sure how to get around it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? true : false;

$(window).load(function() {
if(!isMobile) {
$('.rmm').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
$('.social').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
 $('.filmpress').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
 $('.filmpress2').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
$('.arrow').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
$('.venice').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
  $('.title').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
 $('.logo h3').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
$('#bgbig').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 0) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
$('.logo h2').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can join all those selectors together to have a single function. Secondly, if the elements are `display: none` by default, then you need to use `show()` on them when a mobile device is used. Try this:

```
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? true : false;

$(window).load(function() {
    var $elems = $('.rmm, .social, .filmpress, .filmpress2, .arrow, .venice, .title, .logo h3, #bgbig, .logo h2');
    if (isMobile) {
        $elems.show();
    }
    else {
        $elems.each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay((i + 4) * 250).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that Rory it helped a lot! appreciate the help.